# Issue with std::shared_ptr, inheritance, and template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm trying to use template argument deduction with inheritance and `std::shared_ptr`. As you can see in the sample code below, I'm passing a `shared_ptr<Derived>` to a templated non-member function, which should do template argument deduction. If I manually name the type everything works, and if I let it do template argument deduction it doesn't. It would *seem* as though the compiler couldn't figure out the type, however the error message shows that it did. I'm not sure what's going on here, and I would appreciate any input. (Visual Studio 2010)

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base<int> {};

template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<Base<T> > ptr) {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> myfoo(std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived)); // Compiles
   func(myfoo);    // Compiles
   func<int>(std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));  // Compiles
   func(std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));  // Doesn't compile. The error message suggests it did deduce the template argument.

   return 0;
}
```

The error message:

```
5> error C2664: 'func' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              _Ty=Derived
5>          ]
5>          and
5>          [
5>              _Ty=Base<int>
5>          ]
5>          Binding to reference
5>          followed by
5>          Call to constructor 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr<Derived>(std::tr1::shared_ptr<Derived> &&,void **)'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              _Ty=Base<int>
5>          ]
5>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory(1532) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              _Ty=Base<int>
5>          ]
5>
```

Comment: Here's what GCC 4.7.3 has to say about it, FYI:
`t.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t.cpp:16:47: note:   mismatched types 'Base<T>' and 'Derived'
t.cpp:16:47: note:   'std::shared_ptr<Derived>' is not derived from 'std::shared_ptr<Base<T> >'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the compiler can perform derived-to-base conversions when doing type deduction, `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` does *not* itself derive from `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>`.

There is a user-defined conversion between the two that allows `shared_ptr` to behave like regular pointers with respect to polymorphism, but the compiler won't take into consideration user-defined conversions when performing type deduction.

Without considering user-defined conversiosn, the compiler can't deduce a `T` that would make `shared_ptr<Base<T>>` either identical to `shared_ptr<Derived>` or a base class of `shared_ptr<Derived>` (once again, `shared_ptr<Base<int>>` is *not* a base class of `shared_ptr<Derived>`).

Therefore, type deduction fails.

To work around this problem, you could let the parameter of your function be a simple `shared_ptr<T>` *and* add a SFINAE-constraint that would make sure your overload is picked only when the type of the argument is derived from (or is) an instance of the `Base` class template:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    void deducer(Base<T>);

    bool deducer(...);
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        decltype(detail::deducer(std::declval<T>())),
        void
        >::value>::type* = nullptr>
void func(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4988955d3b682b6e1185a37194b20e2-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Comment: Unfortunately, `decltype` et al. are not available in MSVC10. Why don't you use `is_base_of`?

Comment: @DyP: `decltype` et al. *are* available in MSVC10

Comment: @DyP: Huh, it seems out only `decltype` is available, not "al.:" :D Well, in that case I would need to change things a bit, you're right

Comment: @AndyProwl thank you for the thorough answer. That's along the lines I was thinking until seeing the error message. What puzzled me was that it doesn't say that it couldn't specialize the template, but rather than it can't convert a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` to a `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>`. This looks as though template argument deduction did take place. What do you make of it?

Comment: @Ari: Honestly, I think the compiler is just trying to do you a favor and explain things in terms of what it thinks that you expected: you expected a derived-to-base conversion to take place because `Derived` derives from `Base<int>`, but that's not going to happen because `shared_ptr<Derived>` cannot be converted to a `shared_ptr<Base<int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you write it this way:

```
template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr) {};
```

If you really want to explicitly block the function from being called with something not derived from Base, you could use type_traits/enable_if/etc.